# Google FCM push notification

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm written API for push notification it's working fine on local IIS server,

after i'm move that API into live application then it give me error like
""The remote name could not be resolved: 'fcm.googleapis.com'""

but local IIS is working fine i'm not aware of that error i'm check everything  in development mode no error.

```
EmpLeavesEntities Db = new EmpLeavesEntities();
            string UdeviceID = Db.cst_LoginDetails.Where(x => x.Emp_ID == msg.EmpID).FirstOrDefault().DTokenID;
            if (UdeviceID != null)
            {
                var applicationID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationID"];
                var senderId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["senderID"];
                string deviceId = UdeviceID;
                //ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["deviceID"].ToString();
                WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["createUrl"].ToString());
                tRequest.Method = "POST";
                tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
```

help me out..

Comment: have you solved this issue ? If yes please help me do so..

Comment: Yes i solved that issue

Comment: how you did that ? can you help ? can you post the answer ?

Comment: var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
 tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));